# .NET and PCL (Point Cloud Library)

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, point-cloud-library

I'm looking for some solutions how to use `PCL` in `.NET 4.0` (unsuccessfully:/). I need to use this class: [ConcaveHull](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_concave_hull.html)

I guess it's compiled to `pcl_surface_release.dll` file. Could you help me to load the assembly and use it in `C#`? Maybe, there is some kind of a wrapper in the Web that I missed? Any help appreciated!

Comment: No ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a C++ DLL. Please refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14180/Using-Unmanaged-C-Libraries-DLLs-in-NET-Applicatio).